# How to efficiently convert multiple .gz files to one .tar.gz in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip, tar

I want to combine multiple .gz (not tar.gz) files into one .tar.gz file in Python.

I created temporary files, unzipped them one by one and used Tarfile#addfile.
I was able to do what I wanted to do, but I feel that it is inefficient.
I want to use a buffer.
Is there any efficient way?

Thank you.

The current situation is like this:

```py
def make_tmp(gz_file):
    with open(gz_file) as rt:
        with open("tmp/" + gz_file, mode="wb") as w:
            while True:
                buf = rt.read(65535)
                if not buf:
                    break
                w.write(buf)

gz_files = os.listdir("target_gz")

for gz in gz_files:
    make_tmp(gz)

with tarfile.open("combined.tar.gz", mode="w:gz") as tw:
    for tmp in os.listdir("tmp")
        tw.add(tmp)
```

I hope it looks like this:

```
with tarfile.open("combined.tar.gz", mode="w:gz") as tw:
    for gz in os.listdir("target_gz"):
        with open(gz, mode="rb") as r:
            while True:
                buf = rt.read(65535)
                if not buf:
                    break
                tw.write(gz[:12], buf) # I want to add a file, cut "target_file" and store it
```

Directory tree:

```
.
├── target_gz/
│   ├── foo.gz
│   └── bar.gz
├── tmp/
│   ├── foo.file
│   └── bar.file
├── run.py
└── combined.tar.gz
```

Comment: If your files are already compressed, why do you want to decompress them to after compress again. You can just concatenate all files in your archive. IMHO, this is the most efficient way.

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice in this field and did not know that gz files can be combined as is. Because if target_gz has a deep hierarchy, I want to keep it and put it together.

Comment: I posted an answer if you want to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pathlib
import tarfile

with tarfile.open('combined.tar.gz', 'w') as tw:
    for filename in pathlib.Path('./target_gz').glob('*.gz'):
        print(filename)
        tw.add(filename)
```